# Adding a list inside a GWT List Box

Tags: list, gwt, listbox

I have added an List box and and i have an list of value that needs to be populated in the list box. The only option i could find to add values to the list box is listbox.addItem... where i have to iterate the list of values i have and need to add it one by one. Is there any other way where i can add the entire list in one single call.??

```
private final List<Operation> numberComparisons = Arrays.asList(Operation.EQUAL, Operation.GREATER_THAN, Operation.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, Operation.LESS_THAN, Operation.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, Operation.FILLED_IN, Operation.EMPTY);
```

now i have to add this number comparisons list into

```
ListBox conditionDropDown = new ListBox();
conditionDropDown.addItem(numberComparisons);
```

..... how can i do this...???

Comment: Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but why not inherit from ListBox and add the needed functionality to use it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
class MyListBox extends ListBox {

    public void addAsList(List<Operation> list) {
        for (Operation operation : Operation.values()) {
            addItem(operation.toString());
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
MyListBox conditionDropDown = new MyListBox();
conditionDropDown.addAsList(numberComparisons);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ValueListBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.html) widget; you'll then use a `Renderer` to "generate" the `String` representation of your `Operation` (used to display them to the user in the list).